# Are acid-fast bacteria Gram-positive or Gram-negative?

Tags: microbiology, classification, staining

Both procedures involve using a stain, decolorising agent, and then a second stain. I am tempted to conclude that acid-fast bacteria, which resist decolorisation (eg. by strong carbol fuchsin), also resist decolorisation in the Gram staining test (eg. by gentian violet) and are thus Gram-positive.
After all, there are much fewer acid-fast bacteria than Gram-positive bacteria.

Is this line of thinking incorrect?

[image: http://www.scienceprofonline.com/images/science-image-library/microbiology/staining/differential-bacterial-stain-controls-diagram.JPG]

*Image URL: http://www.scienceprofonline.com/images/science-image-library/microbiology/staining/differential-bacterial-stain-controls-diagram.JPG*

Answer (score 1):

**Taxonomic Classification:**

The [most salient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid-fastness#Notable_acid-fast_structures) acid-fast bacteria are *Mycobacterium spp.*, which are part of a phylum of gram-positive bacteria called *Actinobacteria*. This classification is based on 16S rRNA sequencing. However, based on genetic conservation, [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12356459) makes the claim that they are more closely related to gram negative bacteria.

**Gram Reaction:**

Acid-fast bacteria are characterized by [cell walls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycobacterium#Microbiologic_characteristics) rich in [mycolic acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycolic_acid). This characteristic causes both poor stain penetration and high stain retention which forms the basis of acid-fast stains. However, it also means that crystal violet will not penetrate the cell wall efficiently. [Thus their gram reaction is variable and they generally stain light purple.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19885935) The result is dependent on technique as well as mycolic acid content variation between genera (*Nocardia spp*, for example, are less acid-fast and stain gram positive). Needless to say, their cell walls don't fit well with the classic dichotomy of thin versus thick peptidoglycan which the gram stain differentiates between.

**Example Gram Stains:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

For comparison, the left image is of *Bacillus subtilis*, a gram positive, non-acid-fast bacilli. In the middle is *M. phlei* and on the right is *M. smegmatis*, both of which are acid-fast but show a weakly positive gram reaction. [Images from Napa Valley College.](http://www.napavalley.edu/people/srose/Pages/Biol220.aspx)

[image]
[image]
[image]

*B. subtilis* is again on the left for comparison. In the middle is *M. fortuitum* staining positive but more weakly than *B. subtilis*. On the right is *N. astroides* which is partially acid-fast but stains strongly gram positive. [Images from Microbe Canvas.](http://microbe-canvas.com/)